# AVPlayer not playing video

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"VidName" ofType:@"mov"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];

    AVPlayer *av = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];
    AVPlayerLayer *layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:av];
    [layer setFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];
    [av play];

    NSLog(@"error: %@", av.error);
}
```

The error being logged is NULL.

Comment: 1) `av.error` is NULL; What about `av` itself?  2) Did you check that the file is playable? (e.g., sync via iTunes into device's video library and try to play) 3) I assume `path` is not NULL, otherwise `NSURL` would throw an exception.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

instead of

`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];`

use following line.

```
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:path];
```

Comment: I bet how quickly I would find the solution without this answer.. thank you!

Comment: This gets me every time. Thx!!